# How can I push a git tag to GitHub in AWS Pipeline using a CodeStar Connection?

Tags: git, github, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

I have an AWS Pipeline that is connected to GitHub via CodeStar Connection. The process looks like this:

1. Pull source from GitHub
2. Build project
3. Run tests
4. Deploy

Before (or as part of) step 4 I would like the AWS Pipeline to tag the code with a git tag and then push this back to the repo in GitHub.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't know anything about AWS pipeline, but to push tags to a remote (e.g. GitHub) with Git, you need to use either the `--tags` flag to push all the tags at once (e.g. `git push origin --tags`) or `git push origin <tagname>` to push a single tag. By default, Git does not push tags to remotes. See "Sharing tags" in [the tag chapter of Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) for more info. That said, I don't know whether this helps you in your context.

Comment: @milk Did you figure it out?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and I was able to solve one part of the problem, that is to get the .git folder as part of the clone. For this, you need to select code_build_clone_output=True in your source action. This allows codebuild to clone the repository. But, I am not able to use the same connection to push the tag.

Answer (score -1):

You will need a CodeBuild action before/after Step4 in the Pipeline that will basically execute the git tagging commands and push to origin as mentioned by other commenters. A sample buildspec for CodeBuild project will look like:

```
version: 0.2 

env:
  git-credential-helper: yes


phases: 
  install: 
    runtime-versions: 
      python: 3.7 

  build: 
    commands: 
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - git checkout master
      - git tag ${BUILD_NUMBER} ${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION}
      - git push origin master --tags ${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. git tag applies the tag to the local repository, but codebuild doesn't give you a repository - only a zip file of the given commit.

Comment: @BillShubert what about getting a full clone?

Comment: Yes,  checking out a full clone from within codebuild would work, but it is very slow. I was hoping there was some way to push a tag directly to a remote repository, but I guess not. In the end I created an SQS that has tagging requests, then on a computer that always has the code checked out it monitors that queue. Pretty ugly but I couldn't find anything better.